# Swipe-able views iOS

Tags: ios

I am looking for a framework where you can add n number of views to some sort of view controller, set the order of the views and they will be able to be navigated through using a swipe to the left or right.

Does something like this exist for iOS 4 and 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollView with paging turned on.  Or you could do a UITableView and set a rotation transform on it and its cells.